# How to make circle drawable in Android custom canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable

I want to make in my app possibilty to draw circles by user. The drawing is quite simple - user just press on canvas somewhere and then predefined circle

The difficult part here is to draw it with some drawable (picture) as a fill. It is quite simple when it is about rectangle. Then you just need to write:

```
   Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_background_picture);
   drawable.setBounds(myRectangle);
   drawable.draw(myCanvas);
```

Everything is done on `onDraw()` method of my custom view.

Unfortunatelly there isn't such simple method to make it with circle. The one that I've found is slight modification from [Vogella's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDrawables/article.html#drawables_custom2):

```
    InputStream resource = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.sand);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(resource);

    BitmapShader shader;
    shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP,Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setShader(shader);

    myCanvas.drawRoundRect(myRectangle, 120, 120, paint);
```

At first sight it looks ok, but it's not. This commands make just something like frame on a picture below, so you move hollow circle on a picture and that's all. Not as with rectangle where you actually move rectangular bitmap.

So, my question is - *Is there a way to make circle drawable that can be also moved/resized?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why make a drawable?  You can easily draw a circle via the canvas.drawCircle command.  You can also easily make one via a Path object.

Edit:

If you need a drawable, try making a ShapeDrawable based off an OvalShape.

Comment: Because I need to make background which is not a color, but bitmap. If you have any solution for this I will be glad.

Comment: You can always make a bitmap dynamically.  Create a Bitmap of the right size, create a canvas to it, and draw on the canvas and it will draw to that bitmap.  Then make a bitmap drawable.  May be a better way, but that immediately comes to mind.

Comment: Actually, a much better idea-  use a OvalShape to make a ShapeDrawable.  A circle is just a special case of an oval with the 2 axes of equal length.

Comment: According to your solution I should make circle bitmap and than put it in drawable which will be rectangular, so after all I'll get something ugly? As you might saw in `setBounds()` you define in code size of figure, but in your solution everything has to be defined way before code, and there is now possibility to change its size, so it is not for my.